# Upload a file to a different aws s3 bucket in flutter

Tags: flutter, amazon-s3, flutter-aws-amplify, flutteramplify

In my `Flutter` app I use `Amazon S3` to store my videos and images. I use `amplify_flutter` package to upload files. After following the official documentation of `AWS Amplify`, I created a bucket to upload videos and this bucket is refrenced in `amplifyconfiguration.dart` file. As the documentation states, I am using the following code for file upload:

```
 Amplify.Storage.uploadFile(
    local: file,
    key: key,
    onProgress: (TransferProgress progress) {},
);
```

This code will always upload the file to one specific bucket that is configured in the `amplifyconfiguration.dart` file. However, I want to create another bucket for example only for photos. The problem is, first how to create it, and second how to reference it in the time of uploading the file. Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you able to find the solution for your question? I have the similar use case and would like to upload to a different region along with the different bucket

Comment: @SagarKansara Unfortunately, I haven't found any answer. If you found it, please write it as the answer to the question!